# Bootstrap tables overflowing with long unspaced text

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, css-tables

I'm using Bootstrap and I have a table with a few columns, the last of which sometimes has a long piece of text without spaces. I noticed that under certain screen sizes, the table would overflow its parent div and create ugly overlapping with its sibling table.

I played around with it and I think the problem has to do with the text being unspaced. I created a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/skhFC/2/) that demonstrates what I mean.

As you can see, the top leftmost table is well behaved and simply grows vertically to accommodate more text. However, the bottom left table leads to an overflow on the right due to the long unspaced text and the right column of the bottom left table winds up "under" its sibling.

Does anyone have any tips on how I can fix this so that the very long text gets clipped or partially split onto a new line?

Answer (score 132, accepted):

```
.the-table {
    table-layout: fixed;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

#### Deprecated (i.e. word-wrap)

Add the following styles to your `<table>`

```
.the-table {
    table-layout: fixed;
    over-flow: break-word;
}
```

Then you can adjust your layout via-CSS as you wish.

Comment: fyi only,read somewhere on word-wrap being depreceated, use over-flow:break-word

Comment: @unidha I think you are wrong. You can check the [working draft](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-text/) or the [editor's draft](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-text-3/). That `over-flow` property does not exist. The property we are talking about is named `overflow-wrap` or `word-wrap` as an alternate. Could you provide your source?

Comment: That article just confirms what I said. And it does not mention `over-flow` property. I think you have misread it.

Comment: seem like i misread this statement 'The overflow-wrap property is the replacement for the now-obsolete word-wrap property'

Comment: But this forces you to use fixed layouts. Why can't it just stop expanding the column as the table reaches the container's width and the other columns can't be reduced anymore?

Answer (score 27):

This works without forcing table layout to be fixed
Just add it to td or any

```
.is-breakable {
  word-break: break-word;
}
```

Comment: nice, as simple as that.

Comment: Thanks. You saved my day. Earlier I was using table:fixed which was making all column equal length for columns that have only 1 text.

Answer (score 6):

I was having trouble with these solutions working in Internet Explorer.

I used the following style to get it to finally work.

```
<td style="word-break: break-all">
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use below css. This will wrap the text and apply ... in the end of the text.

e.g. This_is_a_large_text will be changed to This_is_a_lar...

```
td {
  max-width: 120px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

You can also add tool tip to show the complete text value.

```
<td data-toggle="tooltip" title="${text}">${text}</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Albers answer did the trick for me

```
.the-table {
 table-layout: fixed;
 word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

In the JS to load it dynamically add

```
 $("#"  + tableName ).addClass('the-table');
```

Hope it helps!!