# bootstrap responsive table content wrapping

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3, html-table

I have HTML similar to this:

```
    <div class="table-responsive">
         <table class="table borderless">
             <caption>
                  <h3>Announcements</h3>
             </caption>
             <tbody>
                 <tr >
                     <td>                                        
                         If you are waiting for your certificate from your trainer, please contact them. Our turnaround time is between 1-2 months from the time we receive your details from your trainer, which we expect to be at the start of your program. The remainder is dependent upon how quickly your trainer has send in all the required paperwork and made payment, etc.                                       
                     </td>
                 </tr>
             </tbody>
         </table>
     </div>
```

When I view the output in a small view-port, the table is re-sized properly, but the paragraph content in the table cells are not wrapped, so scroll-bars are shown. I expected the responsive behavior would have been to wrap the paragraph content. How do I achieve this?

Comment: The behavior is the same whether I put the content inside <p> or not

Comment: Just have a look at this question it might help you :) 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12195469/bootstrap-tables-overflowing-with-long-unspaced-text

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I ran across the same issue you did but the above answers did not solve my issue.  The only way I was able to resolve it - was to make a class and use specific widths to trigger the wrapping for my specific use case.  As an example, I provided a snippet below - but I found you will need to adjust it for the table in question - since I typically use multiple colspans depending on the layout.  The reasoning I believe Bootstrap is failing - is because it removes the wrapping constraints to get a full table for the scrollbars.  THe colspan must be tripping it up.

```
<style>
@media (max-width: 768px) { /* use the max to specify at each container level */
    .specifictd {    
        width:360px;  /* adjust to desired wrapping */
        display:table;
        white-space: pre-wrap; /* css-3 */
        white-space: -moz-pre-wrap; /* Mozilla, since 1999 */
        white-space: -pre-wrap; /* Opera 4-6 */
        white-space: -o-pre-wrap; /* Opera 7 */
        word-wrap: break-word; /* Internet Explorer 5.5+ */
    }
}
```

I hope this helps

Answer (score 57):

just simply use as below and it will word wrap any long text within a table . No need to anything else

```
<td style="word-wrap: break-word;min-width: 160px;max-width: 160px;">long long comments</td>
```

Comment: Hi UberNeo, your response works and i like it because you do not have to modify anything else except the TD. 

The only point is that you also have to add "white-space:normal" to the style in order to maintain the responsive characteristics of the table, if not, at certain resolutions the wrap is not made and the scroll of the table does not appear.

Comment: Whats the reason behind the value 160px?

Comment: Super Cool its Working for me
Thanks Stay Bless

Answer (score 47):

So you can use the following :

```
td {
  white-space: normal !important; // To consider whitespace.
}
```

If this doesn't work:

```
td {
  white-space: normal !important; 
  word-wrap: break-word;  
}
table {
  table-layout: fixed;
}
```

Comment: thank you so much , this one work for me with bootstrap

Comment: It also works for bootstrap 4 and there is no need to remove the `.table-responsive` class.

Comment: Thanks! This css did the trick. I just pasted and It worked for bootstrap 4.

Comment: Excellent!! It's working perfectly for me in Bootstrap 4.

Answer (score 21):

The behaviour is on purpose:

> Create responsive tables by wrapping any .table in .table-responsive **to make them scroll horizontally on small devices** (under 768px). When viewing on anything larger than 768px wide, you will not see any difference in these tables.

Which means tables are responsive by default (are adjusting their size). But only if you wish to not break your table's lines and add scrollbar when there is not enough room use `.table-responsive` class.

If you take a look at [bootstrap's source](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/10606a73bcbfc6c723d60e2a1069c921afff0d2a/less/tables.less#L171) you will notice there is media query that only activates on **XS** screen size and it sets text of table to `white-space: nowrap` which causes it to not breaking.

## TL;DR; Solution

Simply remove `.table-responsive` element/class from your html code.

Answer (score 12):

**EDIT**

I think the reason that your table is not responsive to start with was you did not wrap in `.container`, `.row` and `.col-md-x` classes like this one

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-12">
     <!-- or use any other number .col-md- -->
         <div class="table-responsive">
             <div class="table">
             </div>
         </div>
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

With this, you can still use `<p>` tags and even make it responsive.

Please see the Bootply example [here](http://bootply.com/112049)

Comment: Hi have edited my answer, please to do check it? I think I have found a better way.

Answer (score 8):

The UberNeo response is Ok and i like it because you do not have to modify anything else except the TD. The only point is that you also have to add "white-space:normal" to the style in order to maintain the responsive characteristics of the table, if not, at certain resolutions the wrap is not made and the scroll of the table does not appear.

```
style="word-wrap: break-word;min-width: 160px;max-width: 160px;white-space:normal;"
```

Answer (score 5):

```css
.table td.abbreviation {
  max-width: 30px;
}
.table td.abbreviation p {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;

}
```

```html
<table class="table">
<tr>
 <td class="abbreviation"><p>ABC DEF</p></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Please add some text describing what you are doing, and what this answer does differently/better than the other existing answers.

Answer (score 4):

Fine then. You can use CSS word wrap property. Something like this :

```
td.test /* Give whatever class name you want */
{
width:11em; /* Give whatever width you want */
word-wrap:break-word;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

use it in css external file.

```
.td-table
{
word-wrap: break-word;
word-break: break-all;  
white-space: normal !important;
text-align: justify;
}
```

Comment: It worked perfectly after removing word-break: break-all;  from the answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Just do this
`style="word-wrap: break-word min-width:; max-width:;"`
and set the `width` you want

Answer (score 0):

In bootstrap 5.0 do like this :

```
 <td class="w-50 text-break">teeeeeeeeeeeeeeest</>
```

You can use w-25 or other things according to [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/sizing/)

Answer (score -1):

Add your new class "tableresp" with table-responisve class and then add below code in your js file

```
$(".tableresp").on('click', '.dropdown-toggle', function(event) {

    if ($('.dropdown-menu').length) {
        var elm = $('.dropdown-menu'),
            docHeight = $(document).height(),
            docWidth = $(document).width(),
            btn_offset = $(this).offset(),
            btn_width = $(this).outerWidth(),
            btn_height = $(this).outerHeight(),
            elm_width = elm.outerWidth(),
            elm_height = elm.outerHeight(),
            table_offset = $(".tableresp").offset(),
            table_width = $(".tableresp").width(),
            table_height = $(".tableresp").height(),

            tableoffright = table_width + table_offset.left,
            tableoffbottom = table_height + table_offset.top,
            rem_tablewidth = docWidth - tableoffright,
            rem_tableheight = docHeight - tableoffbottom,
            elm_offsetleft = btn_offset.left,
            elm_offsetright = btn_offset.left + btn_width,
            elm_offsettop = btn_offset.top + btn_height,
            btn_offsetbottom = elm_offsettop,

            left_edge = (elm_offsetleft - table_offset.left) < elm_width,
            top_edge = btn_offset.top < elm_height,
            right_edge = (table_width - elm_offsetleft) < elm_width,
            bottom_edge = (tableoffbottom - btn_offsetbottom) < elm_height;

        console.log(tableoffbottom);
        console.log(btn_offsetbottom);
        console.log(bottom_edge);
        console.log((tableoffbottom - btn_offsetbottom) + "|| " + elm_height);


        var table_offset_bottom = docHeight - (table_offset.top + table_height);

        var touchTableBottom = (btn_offset.top + btn_height + (elm_height * 2)) - table_offset.top;

        var bottomedge = touchTableBottom > table_offset_bottom;

        if (left_edge) {
            $(this).addClass('left-edge');
        } else {
            $('.dropdown-menu').removeClass('left-edge');
        }
        if (bottom_edge) {
            $(this).parent().addClass('dropup');
        } else {
            $(this).parent().removeClass('dropup');
        }

    }
});
var table_smallheight = $('.tableresp'),
    positioning = table_smallheight.parent();

if (table_smallheight.height() < 320) {
    positioning.addClass('positioning');
    $('.tableresp .dropdown,.tableresp .adropup').css('position', 'static');

} else {
    positioning.removeClass('positioning');
    $('.tableresp .dropdown,.tableresp .dropup').css('position', 'relative');

}
```