# Bootsrap table text not wrapping on less width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Have probably simple question but can't figure out what's wrong. I am using bootstrap table to show the data. The table is responsive and resizing correctly when the user changes the browser size with only one exception which I can't find the solution to.

Look at the picture I liked to.  There are 3 states:
1st when looks normally on full browser size
2nd when user would resize - still ok
3rd when it's been resized a lot then it messes up

Link:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/23pj6w2uu0lz716/fine-fullwith.png?dl=0

Counting on your help.

See my code below:

```
<style type="text/css">
    p {
        /*padding: 5px;*/
        font-size: 13px;
        text-align: center;
        word-wrap:break-word;
    }

    .ar {
        height: 50px;
    }

    .table tbody > tr > td.vert-align_td {
        vertical-align: middle;
    }

    .table thead > tr > th.vert-align_th{
        vertical-align: middle;
    }

</style>

    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
     <div class="col-sm-1 col-lg-2">
    </div>

     <div class="col-sm-11 col-lg-10">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12"> 

                            <div class="content-wrapper"></div>  

                            <div class="panel panel-default">
                                <div class="panel-heading"></div>
                                <div class="panel-body">
                                    <div class="table-responsive">

                                        <table class="table table-bordered table-hover" style="word-wrap: break-word;table-layout: fixed;">
                                            <thead>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <th class="col-md-3 text-center vert-align_th">Nazwa transportu</th>
                                                    <th class="col-md-2 text-center vert-align_th">Typ transportu</th>
                                                    <th class="col-md-2 text-center vert-align_th">Kierowca</th>
                                                    <th class="col-md-1 text-center vert-align_th">Numer rejestracyjny</th>
                                                    <th class="col-md-1 text-center vert-align_th">Firma spedycyjna</th>
                                                    <th class="col-md-1 text-center vert-align_th">Data przyjecia</th>
                                                    <th class="col-md-1 text-right vert-align_th">Przycisk</th>
                                                </tr>
                                            </thead>
                                            <tbody>
                                                @For Each item In Model
                                                    @<tr>
                                                        @*vert-align - look at top in css section*@
                                                         <td class="col-md-3 text-center vert-align_td"><a>@item.NazwaTransportu</a></td>
                                                         <td class="col-md-2 text-right vert-align_td">@item.TypTransportu</td>
                                                         <td class="col-md-2 text-center vert-align_td">@item.Kierowca</td>
                                                         <td class="col-md-1 text-center vert-align_td">@item.NumerRejestracyjny</td>
                                                         <td class="col-md-1 text-center vert-align_td">@item.FirmaSpedycyjna</td>
                                                         <td class="col-md-1 text-center vert-align_td">@item.DataPrzyjecia</td>
                                                         <td class="col-md-1 text-center vert-align_td">
                                                             <a rel="tooltip" class="btn btn-success btn-xs" href="">
                                                                 <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus icon-color"></i>
                                                                 dodaj
                                                             </a>
                                                         </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                Next
                                            </tbody>
                                        </table>
                                    </div>
        </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jrybd.png
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [bootstrap responsive table content wrapping](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21587813/bootstrap-responsive-table-content-wrapping)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bootstrap Tables contain the CSS attribute `white-space: nowrap;` on every table cell (`<td>`). This comes by adding the class `table-responsive`. You can however reset this attribute with the following CSS snippet:

```
.table tbody > tr > td.vert-align_td,
.table tbody > tr > th.vert-align_th {
   white-space: normal;
}
```

Comment: thanks, that's working. However i am just thinking if the table is very resized is there way instead of wrapping down text that better to show besides horizontal scroll down that way and i could define from what moment it should be presented and then text will be then normally shown and user could use this scroll. Hope you get what i ment... :)

Comment: ssc do you know how to do that?

Comment: @JohnDoe I'm not sure what you mean, but I think you do not like that the column width is very small, so that the text is vertical. You could override the ``width: 100%;`` property of the ``.table`` (with ``width: auto;``) and get a scrollable table. I would however add a max-width to every ``<td>`` to prevent the table to get too wide.