# Change the width of a table in Drupal?

Tags: drupal, width

I am working on a page in Drupal and there is text in a table that is being cut off. In order to make the text visible, I think I need to change the width of the table but I am not sure how to do that. Any help would be great.

https://www.mailman.columbia.edu

Answer (score 0):

There are many suggestions to your question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21587813/bootstrap-responsive-table-content-wrapping). I don't have code to look at so hopefully I guide you in the right direction. I would definitely see if `white-space: pre-wrap;` fixes the responsiveness.